# Checking if a number already exists in an a VBA array

Tags: excel, vba

I have a short piece of code that checks if the calculated number "Birthday(i,0)" already exist in the array "Birthday" and if it does to exit the For counter.  Is there a simpler way of testing if "Birthday(i,0)" already exist without using a For Counter to check against every element of the array "Birthday".

Many thanks in advance.

The code is below:

```
 For i = 1 To MaxPeople

         Birthday(i, 0) = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(Rnd() * 365, 0)

         For j = 1 To i - 1
             If Birthday(i, 0) = Birthday(j, 0) Then
                   NumberofPeople = i
                   Exit For
             End If

         Next j

         If NumberofPeople > 0 Then Exit For

  Next i
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim rv

'find the position of a value in the first dimension of an array
rv = Application.Match(yourDate, Application.Index(Birthday, 0, 1), 0)
'if not found, rv will be an error value
If IsError(rv) Then
    Debug.Print "Not found"
Else
    Debug.Print "Found at pos " & rv
End If
```

Comment: Posting from blackberry. I already had the answer typed. The moment I pressed submit, I was horrified to notice that the connection died on me lol... My answer is slightly different though :)

Comment: I'm partial to the Match method. +1

Comment: Siddharth - impressive amount of typing from a blackberry! One reason I only often comment is the iPad typing experience...

Comment: Yeah! I was planning on posting the above answer via BB but then fortunately my connection revived. BTW typing emails on 9860 torch has somewhat made my typing skill amazing! :P

Comment: Hi Tim, Thank you for your answer.  I tried it and it always finds a match. Maybe be there is other things in my code that is causing this.  So below is the full function code I have.  I hope you maybe be able to help.  Many thanks.

Comment: Don't add the value until after you've checked the array for a match.

Answer (score 0):

See if this example helps? It uses a delimiter to join the array and then uses the `INSTR` to find the value in the array.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim n As Long
    Dim MyArray(5, 0) As Long
    Dim Delim As String

    n = 4

    Delim = Chr$(1)

    MyArray(0, 0) = 2
    MyArray(1, 0) = 3
    MyArray(2, 0) = 4
    MyArray(3, 0) = 5
    MyArray(4, 0) = 1

    If InStr(1, Delim & Join(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(MyArray), Delim) & _
    Delim, Delim & n & Delim, 1) Then
        Debug.Print "Exists"
    Else
        Debug.Print "Does Not Exist"
    End If
End Sub
```